# Selenium grid execution - How to upload multiple files together(at one time) to webpage using sendkeys

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-grid

We are running Selenium bdd scenarios over selenium Grid. Browser- chrome and O.S. Windows(for node machines)
We have a scenario to upload multiple files to a webpage.
I am using following code for handling remote execution -

```
WebElement El = driver.findElement(By.id("'fileUploadField'"));
((RemoteWebElement) El ).setFileDetector(new LocalFileDetector());
El.sendKeys("<absolute path of files separated by '\n'>");
```

In local execution, if we provide absolute path of files separated by '\n' to 'sendkeys' method, it works well. It uploads all files to webpage.

Issue is - 
In selenium grid execution, same approach fails without showing any error by selenium.It does not recognize the file paths.
How can I make it work on remote execution too?
Basically files should be sent through the grid to node machine and uploaded to the webpage.
Above code works on remote execution if I provide just one file path.

Is this an open bug with Selenium?

Answer (score 0):

Multi-file uploads are not-yet supported by selenium unfortunately. That it works for you locally is a small miracle in the first place.

Comment: thanks for reply. ya, locally if we provide file paths separated by "\n" to chrome, it works using sendkeys method. I think the way RemoteWebElement has implemented sendkeys method, thats the culprit As it takes just one file at a time and so it cant transfer bunch of files through the grid to node machine